# Generating JSON string from NSDictionary throws an exception

Tags: objective-c, json, macos

I'm trying to make a json string in such way:

```
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:JSONDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString* json = nil;
if (! jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
} else {
    json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

where JSONDictionary initializes as:

```
NSDictionary *JSONDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: dateString, @"start",  [self.currentlyConnectedPeripheral UUID], @"device_id", [self.currentlyConnectedPeripheral name], @"device_name", rrs, @"rates", @"123", @"id", nil];
```

but my application raises an exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__NSCFType)' ***
```

What is my problem and how can I make it work?

Comment: OK, what type does `[self.currentlyConnectedPeripheral UUID]` return?

Comment: <sigh> What's `dateString`, `[self.currentlyConnectedPeripheral UUID]`,  `[self.currentlyConnectedPeripheral name]` and `rrs`. One of those isn't a type that can be JSON serialised (one of them will be `__NSCFType`!)

Comment: [self.currentlyConnectedPeripheral UUID] returns CBUUIDRef object, probably it is the real problem of my code, thank you for pointing me to this

Comment: It is **clearly** telling you that there is an invalid (for JSON) object in the dictionary.  Objects can only be NSString, NSNumber, NSNull, NSDictionary, or NSArray.  NSLog your dictionary to find out what's in it.